# Solar inverter shuts down when refrigerator is connected and utilities shut down

Tags: batteries, inverter, solar-energy, stabilizer

I'm not an electric engineer so apologize if the description is incorrect. So we recently got solar panels set up (1680 W, 280x6) with two 12 V 130 Ah batteries and a 2.5 kW inverter. The system easily runs all our necessary appliances including a fridge which is connected via a stabilizer and the inverter displays a load of 50%. However, whenever the main utility is cut off with our fridge connected, the inverter shuts off displaying a short circuit/temperature peak error. This happens during daylight as well when everything is running on solar anyways. This only happens when the fridge is connected.

My question is if the system is running the fridge smoothly during daylight, shouldn't that continue when main utility is cut off since it was on PV already?

Comment: The AC generated by the inverter needs to be in phase with the utilities AC. Thus, most inverters look for the utilities AC to "lock onto". If it's not present they shut down.

Comment: The inrush current of your fridge is more than 2.5 kW. Common issue.

Comment: The inverter should always shut off for safety reasons whenever the main utility feed is disconnected, not just when the fridge is running.

Comment: @SimonRichter with batteries, this isn't necessarily a grid tie inverter, and probably isn't. There are also off-grid inverters which accept an optional grid connection as an auxiliary source.

Comment: @user_1818839, yes, but the principle of least surprise still applies. An electrician turning off the main breaker would be surprised to find any appliance in the house still powered, so it is a common legal requirement that PV systems must shut down if grid power is unavailable.

Comment: @SimonRichter not in places with no grid connection... My son's house is grid independent and 100% solar.

Comment: @winny by that logic, shouldn't it shut down immediately when a fridge is connected during daylight? it only shuts down when the utility feed is cut.

Comment: @SimonRichter I live in a 3rd country where the utility is shut for 3-4hrs a day. Our solar isn't grid-tied, it has batteries, appliances run on PV during daylights, utility during nighttime, and battery during a nighttime power outage.

Comment: @Unimportant It doesn't always shut down when utility AC is turned off, only when the fridge is connected :/

Comment: Depends. You are not clear in your question how everything is set up. _"whenever the main utility is cut off"_ leads me to believe it runs straight off the grid in this case and hence no inrush supply issues.

Comment: This sounds like a tricky problem. Some things that could maybe help are to make sure the DC cable from the battery to the inverter is sized correctly, and also to get a bigger inverter, or a separate inverter just for the refrigerator. I think Simon Richter is mistaken. To my knowledge, most inverters and transfer switches do not behave the way Simon suggests.

Comment: @osama, After the mains AC utility is cut, are you able to reset the solar PV system and run it normally with the fridge connected?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty with fridges is that they take a large power surge when they start up.

The motor is operating a compressor pump to pump refrigerant around the circuit.  For a fraction of a second when the thermostat turns the pump on, the fluid is stationary, and the motor is stalled.  For that moment, it takes a far higher current.  Once the refrigerant is circulating, the current drops to normal.

This doesn't bother a mains supply that's capable of supplying hundreds (or even thousands) of amps for a short period.  But it's enough to cause an inverter to drop out.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an informed guess - based on long experience in a range of related issues.

The described problem could be caused by the inverter output dropping briefly during mains loss and the fridge presenting an abnormal load as a result of the tremporary drop in power input.
This, of course, may not be the problem but is worth investigating.

If you monitor the mains feed to the fridge when the mains is interrupted you can see if there is in fact a disturbance to the AC feed.
An oscilloscope would provide best information but you could use a meter or even a light bulb.

Possible solutions include:

- Add a UPS to power the fridge and thus isolate the friedge from mains glitches. The UPS needs to be able to handle the fridge's startup current. Its battery can be modest as it is needed only to power the UPS long eniugh to prevent the "glitches".
- Arrange a relay (or other circuitry)to disconnect the fridge immediately mains power is lost and to reconnect it some while afterwards. This allows the fridge to drop back into "properly off" mode and then restart in the normal manner. As normal startup does not cause problems this should not either. One possible exception is trying to start the fridge in the middle of a cycle where compressor load would be high if stopped and started. Allowing a suitably long time before  restart would deal with this.
- An "informal" solution which may work and which I have found useful in some situations where waveform is not ideal is to power the fridge via an isolating transformer. These may be able to be acquired at a small fraction of new price. The transformer aids in waveform   shaping and provides a small energy store for part of a waveform. The existing stabiliser would hopefully do this job already.

You can test this "theory" by disconnecting input mains either with the fridge connected or with the fridge disconnected as shortly as possible **before** the mains disconnection and then restarted shortly afterwards.

IF the fault appears to be solved by removing the fridge immedately before the occurence of the mains outage I/we would be able to offer guidance re a suitable circuit to do this automatically. This would probably involve a relay and a simple restart timing circuit.